# Button not showing in View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode7

My button is not visible in the view controller nor its visible during running. Whats the problem here?

[image: Invisible button]

Comment: are you trying add bar button in navigation bar via Interface Builder?

Comment: @Rishab you can always use help to learn `how to post`.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara will do

Comment: @Narayana Just dragging the button and dropping on the grey area

Comment: @Rishab is that grey area default navigation bar or your custom view?

Comment: its connected to a navigation controller but its a simple view controller.

Comment: Drag the bar button item to the navigation bar not simple uibutton.

Comment: @pkc456  it went to the bottom left corner.??

Comment: @pkc456 I want on the top right corner. When the keypad comes up the left bottom corner will be hidden.

Comment: @pkc456, I have tried UIButton on the navigation and the bar button item and both works.

Comment: @Rishab, try removing the navigation controller form this view controller and then embedding this view controller into a new navigation controller.

Comment: @ArpitDhamane ok will try